# Unable to sort the data with Comparator in android

Tags: android, algorithm, sorting, comparator

I'm trying to make a code to sort the data for my list in the following order and know that I have to use a Comparator, however I have no clue how to implement the following logic into the comparator. Some help or examples will be great ! I would love to hear from you.

```
final private ArrayList<BookItem> books = new ArrayList<>();

Collections.sort(books, compareBooks);
```

The way I want the list to be sorted as follows

Display order

1. The lower  the sort_order number, the item will be shown  The newer
2. the date of the start_date is, the higher the item will be shown
3. The bigger the ID value,  the item will be

```java
private Comparator<BookItem> compareBooks = (o1, o2) -> {
    if (o1.sort_order == BookItem.ORDER && o2.sort_order != BookItem.ORDER) {
        return -1;
    } else if (o1.start_date != BookItem.START && o2.start_date == BookItem.START) {
        return 1;
    } else if (o1.ID == BookItem.ID && o2.ID == BookItem.ID) {
        return 0
    } 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it step by step as in your list of sort attributes

1. The lower the sort_order number, the item will be shown The newer
2. the date of the start_date is, the higher the item will be shown
3. The bigger the ID value, the item will be

a

```
 private Comparator<BookItem> compareBooks = (o1, o2) -> {
    int result =o1.sort_order - o2.sort_order
    if(0==result){
      result=o1.start_date.compareTo(o2.start_date);
    }
    if(0==result){
      result=o1.ID-o2.ID;
    }
 };
```

Most likely I messed up the order of at least one of your attributes, but the idea should be clear.